CyberPanel Node.js App Hosting Returns 404 - Configuration Issue? Node express app with Cyberpanel and openlightspeed
I am trying to host an Express.js application on CyberPanel with OpenLiteSpeed. I followed the official documentation to configure the Node.js app. However, the app is not working, and I keep getting a "404 Not Found" error when accessing it.
Below is my current virtual host configuration:


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abcd.in
    ServerAlias www.abcd.in
    ServerAdmin mkuser@gmail.com
    SuexecUserGroup abcd9310 abcd9310
    DocumentRoot /home/abcd.in/app
    CustomLog /home/abcd.in/logs/abcd.in.access_log combined

    <IfModule LiteSpeed>
        CacheRoot lscache
        CacheLookup on
    </IfModule>

    # App Server Configuration for Node.js
    <Context /node >
        Type                    appserver
        URI                     /node/
        Location                /home/abcd.in/public_html/
        BinaryPath              /usr/bin/node
        ApplicationType         node
        MaxConns                100
        Env                     NODE_ENV=production
    </Context>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName abcd.in
    ServerAlias www.abcd.in
    ServerAdmin mkuser@gmail.com
    SuexecUserGroup abcd9310 abcd9310
    DocumentRoot /home/abcd.in/app
    CustomLog /home/abcd.in/logs/abcd.in.access_log combined

    <IfModule LiteSpeed>
        CacheRoot lscache
        CacheLookup on
    </IfModule>

    # App Server Configuration for Node.js
    <Context /node >
        Type                    appserver
        URI                     /node/
        Location                /home/abcd.in/public_html/
        BinaryPath              /usr/bin/node
        ApplicationType         node
        MaxConns                100
        Env                     NODE_ENV=production
    </Context>

    # SSL Configuration
    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcd.in/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abcd.in/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>



not working
I have followed this https://docs.openlitespeed.org/config/appserver/nodejs/#__tabbed_1_2
Expected Behavior:
The Node.js application should load at http://abcd.in/ or https://abcd.in/.
Issue:
I consistently get a "404 Not Found" error instead of the app's expected output.
What I've Tried:
Verified the app is working by running it locally with node server.js.
Checked file permissions for /home/abcd.in/app and /home/abcd.in/public_html/.
Restarted OpenLiteSpeed after making changes.
Followed the documentation for setting up Node.js in OpenLiteSpeed.
Environment:
CyberPanel version: (add your version here)
OpenLiteSpeed version: (add your version here)
Node.js version: (add your version here)
Operating System: (e.g., Ubuntu 20.04)
Questions:
Is my  block correctly configured for a Node.js app?
Should the DocumentRoot and Location paths point to the app's directory or the public_html directory?
What could be the cause of the "404 Not Found" error?
